# Global variables values Node.js are missing on App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, global, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a Node.js service deployed on App Engine which uses the Dialogflow fulfillment library. The scenario is this: I have an async function which retrieves the credentials using Secret manager and, with that info, calls an API that brings a url instance and a token back. This is a server-to-server authentication (OAuth), so it is the same for all users that access it. I set those values in global variables, like this:

```
let globalUser = "";
let globalPass = "";
...

async function credentials() {
    const credentials = await secretsInstance.getCredentials();
    const parsedCredentials = JSON.parse(credentials);
    const user = parsedCredentials.user;
    const pass = parsedCredentials.pass;
    //setting the values to the global variables
    globalUser = user;
    globalPass = pass;
    
    //call the authentication API - in the callback I set other global variables
    await authApiInstance.authenticate(user, pass, callback);
}
```

After the callback function is called, I set the instance url and token to the global variables.
The token gets expired each 20 minutes, so I need to keep it updated. For that I call a setInterval function in which I call the `authApiInstance.authenticate(...)`

The problem here is that, when receiving a POST request coming from Dialogflow, I need to call another API that needs that url, which in this stage is empty for the first time, so it throws ECONNREFUSED. Then if I call the server other times, the variable is set.

The logs in GCP are like this:

```
2020-08-14 23:29:49.078 BRT
"Calling the loadQuestions API

2020-08-14 23:29:49.078 BRT
"The url is: /services/…

2020-08-14 23:29:49.091 BRT
"CATCH: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80"

2020-08-14 23:29:49.268 BRT
dialogflowGatewayProdxjmztxaet4d8Function execution took 764 ms, finished with status code: 
200

2020-08-14 23:29:49.278 BRT
{ message_id: '39045207393', status: 200 }

2020-08-14 23:29:49.289 BRT
"Credentials ok"

2020-08-14 23:29:49.976 BRT
"Url set"
```

As it can be seen, the credentials and url were set after the API got called, so it didn't have a url to proceed successfully with the call.

I could call the function inside the POST, each time there is a request to guarantee that it will always exist, but the performance would be lost, especially dealing with Chatbots that must be quick.

I also tried the warmup approach, in which theoretically it would be called when deploying and changing the instance (but it could not be called, as by docs):

```
app.get('/_ah/warmup', (req, res) => {
   credentials();
});
```

How could I approach this? I'm pretty new to Node.js and the server world.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`credentials();` by itself. no need to do it in express. The issue i would be race condition on the the shared credential.

crude example assuming the event loop has only these script in queue  :
let say, you have 2 concurrent users A and B. A request and found the credential expire which in turn request new credential. B request before the credential return from A request, which in turn request another credential. Based on node eventloop, A then get credential_A , B will get credential B. If your third party only allow single credential then A will get an error from api call.

So the approach would be to forward the credential related task to one module, which manages the credential. background task or on request ( get token  it expires on request) will face the same race problem.  since node doesn't have context of thread, it is simple.

```js
let credential = {}

let isUpdating = false;

const _updateCrediental = (newCrediential){ 

  //map here
  
  
}

const _getCredential = async()=> {

  try{
  
    if(!updating){
    
      updating = true;
      
      const newCrediential = await apiCall();
      
      updateCrediential(newCrediential);
      
      
      updating = false;
      
      return credential;
      
    }else{
    
      return false;
    }
    
  }catch(err){
    
    throw err;
  }
 }
 
 
 export.getCredential = ()=>{
   
      if(credentialIsValid()){

        return credential;
        
      }
      return __getCredential();
   }
  /// check the return if it promise type then waaait for it if its false then wait for certain time and check again.
```

An improvement to this would be using event to instead of using timeout.

I myself would prefer work with database as well as you might want to log credential generation as well. Most database promise certain kind of transaction or locking. (feel safer)